# QPixmap doesn't read SVG file

Tags: qt, file, svg, qt4, qpixmap

Good Morning, I have the following problem:

I have 2 PCs, the first one with MVS and Qt release 4.7.2 and the second one without MVS and without Qt.

I am using QPixmap in order to read the SVG and/or PNG files. If I launch my tool on the first PC like release out of the MSV environment, it runs very well. The pointer returned is not 0 and I can open PNG and SVG files.

When I copy my .exe with the dlls needed to the second pc, the tool runs. But when I try open a .svg file, I get a message box with an error because the pointer returned is 0. If I instead open a PNG file, it works.

Both PCs run Windows 7 with SP1.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: There are plenty of dlls needed to be [included](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#qt-plugins) during deployment. In `C:/Qt/4.7.2/<compiler directory>/` you should see a folder "plugins", with a subfolder "imageformats" with plenty of dlls for various image formats. That folder needs to be copied during deployment and be next to the executable.

Comment: thanks but I have already used the following dll:

Comment: QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll,QtNetwork4.dll , QtSvg4.dll and qsvgd4.dll. In my opinion this problem is due at the absence of MSV and qt in the second PC, but which files?

Comment: Use the `windeployqt.exe` utility. I'm fairly certain Qt4 has it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG icons not showing up in Qt4 release build in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318990/svg-icons-not-showing-up-in-qt4-release-build-in-windows)

Comment: Hi Jon, can you explain me the tool windeployqt.exe?

Comment: I fixed the bug!! Using listdll.exe, I have seen that dll used are the following: QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, QtNetwork4.dll, QtSvg4.dll and ALSO QtXm14.dll. Furthermore there are a lot of dll look for under: c:\Qt\4.7.2\plugins\imageformats\qqif4.dll, qico4.dll, qjpeg4.dll, qmng4.dll, qsvg4.dll and qtiff4.dll. So I create during the deployment a new directory c:/Qt/4.7.2/plugins/imageformats/{*.dll} and all run. But My question is why?...Why I didn't have a missing dll error while run of the program?

Comment: And Why I must create a new directory c:/qt... with the dll,? I always knew that was enough to copy the dll together with the *.exe!!

Comment: For Jon, windeployqt.exe doesn't exist for QT rel. 4.7.2