# qt 4.8.6 windows 10 and svg

Tags: qt, svg

I compiled a piece of code using Qt 4.8.6 (minGW 32bits) on a PC with SEVEN Pro 64 to open svg file (countries map images).

It's working fine on Windows 7.
When I launch the exe on a PC with Windows 8.1 or Windows 10), the code executes but no image appears on the screen.

So, to have an idea of this troubleshooting, I try to open an other format of image. With JPG or PNG, all is OK. The image is shown on the screen!

Last, I add a check in the code to see if the svg file is opened...

```
QString nom = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Select the map...","/Home","Images (*.jpg *.png *.svg)");
if (nom.isEmpty())
    return;

bool ok = m_pix.load(nom);//try with image.svg
if (ok)
    m_scene->addPixmap(m_pix);//add the pixmap
else
{
    status("Image file not loaded!");
    return;
}
```

Why is the svg file not loaded on Windows 10 while the same jpg or png is opened?

this code works fine under Seven but not with Windows 8 or higher.

NB: I check the properties of the file and I also try to use compatibility mode for the code but without anay success...

Comment: Note that Windows 8 and Windows 10 [aren't supported by Qt 4.8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/supported-platforms.html). Qt 4.8 is really old - you might want to try upgrading.

Comment: Did you read this, already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318990/svg-icons-not-showing-up-in-qt4-release-build-in-windows

Comment: @tambre: well, ok 4.8.6 is a little bit old now but, for some use, when comparing the amount size of all the necessary files to those of Qt 5.9.2 (which I also installed on my PC under Seven), the later one is at least 2.5 times bigger as I get no extra...

Comment: @tambre: moreover, the code compiled with Qt4 not only works fine on Seven but also on W8 an W10 if I limit the image formats to JPG or PNG! Surprinsigly, SVG only isn't working even with qsvg4.dll at the right place...

Comment: @vec44 I would guess QT's libraries have got more features over time (thus the size has increased), but any compiler worth its weight should be able to optimize out stuff you don't use, if linking statically.

Comment: @tambre Yes, I understand...

Comment: @tambre As suggested by a user, before trying with W10, I add a check of all the formats available to see if svg is accepted.

Comment: @tambre as we could expect, svg is not in that list (while executed on Seven, I find svg and svgz. If I look at into my svg files with EXIFTOOL, I find image/svg+wml and I wonder if the problem is not related to xml (encoded text?. I tried to add QXml.dll to the imageformats directory but without more success!